# search from editText in recyclerview where i am getting items from API using retrofit

Tags: java, android, search, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I found many solution bute they searching in only given list aor may they search through searchview.But In my case I have to search using edite text.  search from editText in recyclerview where i am getting items from API using retrofit.here is my code of recyclerview adapter and the class..
 i want to filter list of collectionpoint on the basis of name .
thanx in advance

```
private List<CollectionPoint> collectionPointList;

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView collectionPointId, collectionPointName;
        private int collectionPointID;

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            collectionPointId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCollectionPointID);
            collectionPointName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCollectionPointName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), Appointments.class);`
            intent.putExtra("CollectionPointID", collectionPointID);

            Appointments.CollectionPointID = collectionPointID;
            FragmentProcedure.CollectionPointID = collectionPointID;

            itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public CollectionPointAdapter(List<CollectionPoint> collectionPointList1) {
        this.collectionPointList = collectionPointList1;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.collectionpointlistitems, viewGroup, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CollectionPoint collectionPoint = collectionPointList.get(position);
        holder.collectionPointId.setText("ID - " + String.valueOf(collectionPoint.getID()));
        holder.collectionPointName.setText(collectionPoint.getName());

        holder.collectionPointID = collectionPointList.get(position).getID();

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return collectionPointList.size();
    }


    public void filterList(ArrayList<CollectionPoint> filteredList) {
        collectionPointList = filteredList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Activity :

```
 RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public static GetCollectionPointByUserIDResponse getCollectionPointByUserIDResponse = new GetCollectionPointByUserIDResponse();
    private List<CollectionPoint> collectionPointList = new ArrayList<>();
    CollectionPointAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_collection_point);
        getCollectionPoints();

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.collectionPointRecyclerView);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        TextView logout = findViewById(R.id.logout);
        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CollectionPoints.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.search);
/*        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                filter(s.toString());
            }
        });*/

    }

    private void filter(String text) {
        ArrayList<CollectionPoint> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (CollectionPoint item : filteredList) {
            if (item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }

        mAdapter.filterList(filteredList);
    }

    private void getCollectionPoints() {

        GetCollectionPointByUserIDResquest request = new GetCollectionPointByUserIDResquest();
        request.Token = Login.session.Token;
        request.SessionID = Login.session.ID;
        request.UserID = Login.loginResponse.UserInfo.get(0).ID;
        request.MethodName = "GetCollectionPointBuUserID";

        BusinessService businessService = APIClient.getClient().create(BusinessService.class);
        Call<GetCollectionPointByUserIDResponse> call = businessService.GetCollectionPointBuUserID(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<GetCollectionPointByUserIDResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetCollectionPointByUserIDResponse> call, Response<GetCollectionPointByUserIDResponse> response) {
                try {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        getCollectionPointByUserIDResponse = response.body();
                        assert getCollectionPointByUserIDResponse != null;
                        if (getCollectionPointByUserIDResponse.ResponseCode == 1) {
                            collectionPointList = new ArrayList<>(getCollectionPointByUserIDResponse.getCollectionpoint());
                            CollectionPointAdapter collectionPointAdapter = new CollectionPointAdapter(collectionPointList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(collectionPointAdapter);
                        } else if (getCollectionPointByUserIDResponse.ResponseCode == 6) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(CollectionPoints.this, Login.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(CollectionPoints.this, getCollectionPointByUserIDResponse.ResponseMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(CollectionPoints.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GetCollectionPointByUserIDResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(CollectionPoints.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter `Recyclerview` items from `editText` by calling filter method in `addTextChangedListener` and passing `arraylist` to your Adapter class like below code :

```
Private Context context;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(yourLayout);

        context = YourActivity.this;

       editText_filter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                try {
                    if (CollectionPointAdapter != null)
                        //Calling Adapter method
                        CollectionPointAdapter.getFilter().filter(editable); 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    });

    }


    public void setNoDataVisible(int size) { //IF results empty handle UI from adapter.
        try {
            if (size == 0) {
                txtView_noData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                txtView_noData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void getCollectionPoints() {

        GetCollectionPointByUserIDResquest request = new GetCollectionPointByUserIDResquest();
        request.Token = Login.session.Token;
        request.SessionID = Login.session.ID;
        request.UserID = Login.loginResponse.UserInfo.get(0).ID;
        request.MethodName = "GetCollectionPointBuUserID";

        BusinessService businessService = APIClient.getClient().create(BusinessService.class);
        Call<GetCollectionPointByUserIDResponse> call = businessService.GetCollectionPointBuUserID(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<GetCollectionPointByUserIDResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetCollectionPointByUserIDResponse> call, Response<GetCollectionPointByUserIDResponse> response) {
                try {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        getCollectionPointByUserIDResponse = response.body();
                        assert getCollectionPointByUserIDResponse != null;
                        if (getCollectionPointByUserIDResponse.ResponseCode == 1) {
                            collectionPointList = new ArrayList<>(getCollectionPointByUserIDResponse.getCollectionpoint());

                       //Here You're passing List to Adatper, so that we can filter it.

                            CollectionPointAdapter collectionPointAdapter = new CollectionPointAdapter(context, collectionPointList); 
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(collectionPointAdapter);
                        } else if (getCollectionPointByUserIDResponse.ResponseCode == 6) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(CollectionPoints.this, Login.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(CollectionPoints.this, getCollectionPointByUserIDResponse.ResponseMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(CollectionPoints.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GetCollectionPointByUserIDResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(CollectionPoints.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Change your `Adapter` like below code :

```
public class CollectionPointAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CollectionPointAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<CollectionPoint> collectionPointResults;
    private ArrayList<CollectionPoint> mFilteredList;

    public CollectionPointAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<CollectionPoint> collectionPointResults) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.collectionPointResults = collectionPointResults;
        this.mFilteredList = collectionPointResults;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFilteredList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_yours, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        try {
            holder.collectionPointId.setText("ID - " + String.valueOf(mFilteredList.get(position).getID()));
            holder.collectionPointName.setText(mFilteredList.get(position).getName());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    //Filter the adapter interface
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                try {
                    String charString = charSequence.toString();
                    if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                        mFilteredList = collectionPointResults;
                    } else {
                        ArrayList<RefLeadsgivenResult> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (RefLeadsgivenResult row : collectionPointResults) {
                            if (row.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) { //Searching by Name
                                filteredList.add(row);
                            }
                        }
                        mFilteredList = filteredList;
                    }
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ie) {
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                try {
                    mFilteredList = (ArrayList<RefLeadsgivenResult>) filterResults.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    ((YourActivity) mContext).setNoDataVisible(mFilteredList.size());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
    }



    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        @BindView(R.id.collectionPointId)
        TextView collectionPointId; 
        @BindView(R.id.collectionPointName)
        TextView collectionPointName;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i mentioned for you to handle, if search results are empty you can show your UI based on `setNoDataVisible` method.

Comment: Glad to help you